# ¿Detención de colisiones en java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, game, libgdx

Tengo un problemilla con la detención de colisiones.

Esta es la forma en la que chequeo si mi objeto (mario) colisiona con otro objeto (bloque), funciona perfectamente, pero no se como hacer que el objeto se detenga exactamente al colisionar con el objeto.

He intentado algoritmos como los tipicos en gamemaker donde usas una iteración que determine si en tu siguiente posición colisionarás con un objeto para calcular donde debe detenerse el jugador, pero no me ha salido bien. ¿Alguna idea?

Edit: Si lo necesitan,refiéranse a la velocidad del objeto Mario como vX o vY. El objetivo es implementar colisiones precisas.

```
//Chequear colisiones
        public boolean placeMeeting(Mario object1, Block object2) {
    
            float object1x = Math.round(object1.getX());
            float object1y = Math.round(object1.getY());
    
            float object2x = Math.round(object2.getX());
            float object2y = Math.round(object2.getY());
    
            if ((object1x < object2x + object2.getWidth() && object2x < object1x + object1.getWidth() &&
                 object1y < object2y + object2.getHeight() && object2y < object1y + object1.getHeight())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

//Condicional (donde debería ir el código que detenga al jugador)
        if (mario.placeMeeting(mario, block)){
                System.out.println("Colision");
        }
```

Comment: Si `vX` y `vY` es la velocidad de Mario, ponlas en 0 cuando detectas la colisión y Mario se quedará situado en ese lugar.

Comment: Entonces habré comprendido mal el problema que tienes, pensé que solo querías detener el movimiento. Normalmente el movimiento lo determina la velocidad de los ejes generalmente declarados como delta o `dx` y `dy` o `vx` y `vy` en tu caso, y si están en 0 entonces el objeto no se moverá. Igualmente me parecía un poco obvio... en fin.

Comment: Bruh por editar casi elimino el post, lamento el inconveniente xD

Recuerdo bien que en Game Maker solían usar un arreglo que chequeaba la siguiente posición del jugador, y si en esta ocurría una colisión, una variable aumentaba una unidad hasta llegar a la cantidad de pixeles que faltarían para que ocurra la colisión.

Intente recrear ese ejemplo en LibGDX, pero simplemente no funciona como debería, solo funciona arriba y izquierda, y si intento arreglarlo termina funcionando solo abajo y derecha (juraría haber tenido este problema antes, pero la solución de aquella vez no funciono aquí).

Comment: Suponiendo que tus objetos sean imágenes, desde que vértice estás realizando los cálculos ? Aparte de eso, la idea que se me ocurre es que en vez de devolver true o false, retorne la cantidad de pixeles que quedan hasta colisionar con el, si la distancia que recorre mario en 1 paso es inferior a la distancia de colision, entonces permitirle avanzar solamente la cantidad de pixeles que quedan hasta llegar al objeto.

Comment: Desde los bordes de las texturas, son imagenes estaticas de 24x24 pixeles, veía mucho mas dinamico trabajar sin usar rectangles.

Btw eso es lo que implemente y no funciono, esta en el post, amigo.